# How can I get the data from PagingData<T> object before it is reached to ViewHolder?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-paging-library

I want to get the data of a `PagingData<T>` object in some in-between class like `ViewModel` before it is reached to the `Adapter` and gather its property as a list.
I can access the code by the `flatmap` but I don't want to apply any changes. Also, this kind of access is useless because the entire block runs after subscribing to the observable is finished in `ViewModel` so it is unreachable by the `ViewModel` running.

```
    private fun getAssignedDbList(): Flowable<PagingData<T>> {
        var list  = mutableListOf<Int>()
        return repository.getList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap { pagingData ->
                Flowable.just(pagingData.map
                { foo -> 
                    list.add(foo.id)
                    foo })
            }
    }
```

Another example, let's assume that we have this scenario:
I'm going to call another API before the Paging data is reached to the view holder. The paging data needs to be filled with a new API call response. How can I wait for the second API call to update the data of paging data?

```
 private fun getListFromAPI(): Flowable<PagingData<T>> {
        var list  = mutableListOf<Int>()
        return repository.getList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap { pagingData ->
              //call another API calls and waiting for a response to change some of the fields of 
              //paging data
            }
    }
```

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/getting-on-same-page-with-paging-3.html